# XElement parses my XML file as one huge element, how do I fix?

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

So I am trying to parse through some XML which is being returned from a REST API call. The XML looks like this (with many more `<link>`'s of course):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<response status="Ok">
<links>
<link id="79380" hint="Some Text" linkDescription="This is the GET url for this Customer." link="/customer/79380" httpMethod="GET"/>
</links>
</response>
```

I am loading the XML file using the following code:

```
Stream resStream = response.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(resStream);

XElement doc = XElement.Load(reader);
```

I then loop through the elements like so:

```
IEnumerable<XElement> List =
   from el in doc.Descendants("links") select el;

foreach (XElement e in List)
{
   test += e.ToString();
}
```

It only loops through once and test is just a string that contains the entire XML file. My goal is to get the value of the "id" attribute from each element and place them in a list.

I have tried various things and I can't seem to get anything back but one huge string.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var idList = doc.Descendants("link").Select(x => (int)x.Attribute("id"));
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you! Would you mind explaining what I was doing wrong? I'm still learning this LINQ to XML stuff.

Comment: if you want to get link elements use `doc.Descendants("link")`, you were using `doc.Descendants("links")` and that's why you were getting the `links` elements instead of `link`